# How can I pass multiple instructions in one ssh command?

Tags: command-line, scripts, ssh

I'm having a problem that I've been stuck on for a while. I did a lot of research and quite a few answers came up but these don't seem to fit in my case. This is what I'm looking to do:

Through the ssh command, I want to be able to run multiple commands that will come to run on a remote server. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do, with my explanations.

In a script containing parameters, I want to run a ssh while passing a list of instructions contained in a variable called $SSH_CMD :

```
ssh -tv $IP "$SSH_CMD";
```

And the variable is set like this :

```
    SSH_CMD="$(cat <<-EOF
        
        touch $DIR/test0.txt;
        if [ -d $DIR ]; then
                touch $DIR/test1.txt;
                if [[ -n $(find $DIR -type f -mtime +7) ]]; then
                        touch $DIR/test2.txt;
                        sudo find $DIR -name abc -type f -mtime +7 -delete;
                fi
        else
                touch $DIR/test3.txt;
        fi
        touch $DIR/test4.txt;
        EOF
        
    )"
```

Thanks to verbose, I was able to get this when running the script:

```
    debug1: Sending command:
        
            touch /a_random_dir/test0.txt;
            if [ -d /a_random_dir ]; then
                touch /a_random_dir/test1.txt;
                if [[ -n  ]]; then
                    touch /a_random_dir/test2.txt;
                    sudo find /a_random_dir -name abc -type f -mtime +7 -delete;
                fi
            else
                touch /a_random_dir/test3.txt;
            fi
        
    bash: -c: line4: unexpected argument "]]" for one-argument conditional operator
    bash: -c: line4: Syntax error near « ; »
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
    bash: -c: line4: `if [[ -n  ]]; then'
```

You should know that for test purposes, the .txt created are used by me to know which "path" the script went through. Here I only have the "test0.txt" that was created. And as we can see, the entire "$(find $DIR -type f -mtime +7)" is gone and that's also the case for the "test4.txt". In addition to the errors encountered, I have the impression that the first "if" encounters a problem because I indicate the two possible cases (if the directory exists, and if not), and yet neither the test1.txt nor the test3.txt is created. Any idea why ?

I deliberately removed some passages from the script to make it easier for you to understand, however know that I need to keep the conditions (if) in place.

I thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: When you use an *unquoted* marker `EOF` in a here-document, variables like `$DIR` and command substitutions like `$(find $DIR -type f -mtime +7)` get expanded by the local shell. Presumably the code's original author understood and intended that (although perhaps didn't understand the importance of quoting variable expansions like `"$DIR"`), but it means you will need to have sensible definitions for `$DIR` in your own code.

Comment: After you set your `SSH_CMD` variable, type `echo "$SSH_CMD"` to see what really gets passed to the `ssh` command. This will help you to investigate the issue.

Comment: You're missing an argument in `[[ -n ]]`

Comment: @raj : I did what you suggested, here is the content of the variable, but this is basically the same thing :  
touch /a_random_dir/test0.txt;
if [ -d /a_random_dir ]; then 
 touch /a_random_dir/test1.txt; 
 if [[ -n ]]; then 
  touch /a_random_dir/test2.txt; 
  sudo find /a_random_dir -name abc -type f -mtime +7 -delete;  
 fi 
else 
 touch /a_random_dir/test3.txt;  
fi 
touch /a_random_dir/test4.txt;

Comment: @waltinator : Yes, I'm trying to discover why.

Comment: @TyrellBadd What should be inside brackets in `[[ -n ]]` ? Because that's the part that causes error.

Comment: `if ! find folder/ -type f -mtime +7 -print -quit | ifne false; then echo older; fi` think you should do something like this instead.

Comment: The argument to `[[ -n ]]` is missing because `$(find $DIR -type f -mtime +7)` evaulates to nothing *in the local shell*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understood the origin of the problem, and how to fix it.

Here, absolutely all the problems encountered were related to this passage: if [[ -n $(find $DIR -type f -mtime +7) ]

As explained to me, the $( ) get expanded by the local shell (here in my case, the remote server), while in fact I wanted all these commands to be interpreted directly at script execution before executing the commands on the remote server.

To remedy this, I replaced the $( ) with quotes, and it now works as expected.

Thanks to everyone for the help, and I hope it helps future creators as well.

I wish you a good day.